# Why is this question in my filter results with no matching tags?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, tag-filters

I have an SE filter set across SE for [relayd](/questions/tagged/relayd), [opensmtpd](/questions/tagged/opensmtpd), and [pf](/questions/tagged/pf).

This question is in the search that doesn't have those tags or even those words.

[What would Detect Evil show on a villain who is self righteous and truly believes they are in the right](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/192956/what-would-detect-evil-show-on-a-villain-who-is-self-righteous-and-truly-believe)

[image: whyhere?]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On that site, the [pf](/questions/tagged/pf) tag is synonymized to the [pathfinder-1e](/questions/tagged/pathfinder-1e) tag, which matches the filter you have set up.

Comment: And a mere 6,983 questions tagged, lulz.